# Wine installation failed

Tags: 19.10

```
nidhi@premendra:~/Desktop/wine-4.0.2$ ./configure --enable-wine64
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-wine64
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for cpp... cpp
checking for ld... ld
checking whether gcc -m32 works... no
configure: error: Cannot build a 32-bit program, you need to install 32-bit development libraries.
```

Answer (score 1):

Building Wine from the source is discouraged. A much easier way is using the official [installation guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu). With this method, there is far less chance of things going south, and it ensures your Wine is always kept up to date. Furthermore, with this guide, all the instructions are clearly detailed out in a logical order, making it easier to follow.

Hopefully this is helpful for you :)